# Tutorial – BDD and Dependency Injection in .Net (3)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me in removing this error.Its showing blue line under Result in last second line with bold letters.Errors are:
1'RockPaperScissors.DecisionEngine' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'RockPaperScissors.DecisionEngine' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\MOB140003208\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\Game.cs 42  37  RockPaperScissors
2 Metadata file 'C:\Users\MOB140003208\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\bin\Debug\RockPaperScissors.dll' could not be found    C:\Users\MOB140003208\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissorsTest\CSC RockPaperScissorsTest

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RockPaperScissors
{
public class Game
{


    private string _playerMove;
    private DecisionEngine _decisionEngine;

    public string PlayerMove
    {
        private get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_playerMove))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("PlayerMove");
            return _playerMove;
        }
        set
        {
            _playerMove = value;
        }
    }
    public Game()
    {
        _decisionEngine = new DecisionEngine();
    }

    public Game(DecisionEngine decisionEngine)
    {
        _decisionEngine = decisionEngine;
    }

    public string Result()
    {
        var engine = _decisionEngine;
        var gameResult = engine.Result(Move.Rock, (Move)Enum.Parse(typeof(Move), PlayerMove));
        return gameResult == GameResult.PlayerWins ? "Player Wins!" : "Computer Wins!";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: At a guess, make `DecisionEngine` public

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that `RockPaperScissors.DecisionEngine` is `protected` or has no access modifier applied to it.  Making it `public` would solve this.  `RockPaperScissors.Game.Game` is probably `public`.  Make `RockPaperScissors.DecisionEngine` `public` or give it the same accessibility modifier as `RockPaperScissors.Game.Game`.